# Is it possible support OR in the pattern of Security Namespace Configuration?

Tags: spring-security

I use Spring Security 4.
I want to configure the same Security Namespace Configuration on 2 patterns of URLs.
Something like:

```
<http pattern=("/api/**" OR "/legacyapi/**") …
```

Is `OR` supported?
What is the best way to do it?
Now I have 2 Security Namespace Configurations that different only by pattern and I want to convert it to one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<http request-matcher="regex" pattern=("^(/api/|/legacyapi/)(.*)")
```

The default matcher is `ant`, you can change to `regex`. Please test the regex by yourself.